# What is the drawback of having more instances of enum type other than in the enum declaration?

Tags: java, enums, jls

It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly instantiate an enum type

(§15.9.1). The final clone method in Enum ensures that enum constants can never be cloned, and the special treatment by the serialization mechanism ensures that duplicate instances are never created as a result of deserialization. Reflective instantiation of enum types is prohibited. Together, these four things ensure that no instances of an enum type exist beyond those defined by the enum constants.

What is the drawback of having more instances of enum type other than in the enum
declaration?

Comment: I'm interested to know why you would want more than one instance of an enum type?  An enum is used to represent a fixed set of constants, so by having more than one instance of a constant, that would be the same as wanting to have more than one "number 5", say, in the set of integers.  My counter question would be: what is the advantage of having more than one instance of an enum type?

Answer (score 5):

The drawback is that you're throwing away the statically checkability of enums.

You can statically ensure that a `switch` on an enum value does indeed handle all cases. You can statically ensure that calling a method with an enum does a sane thing. You can statically ensure that there's a translation of every enum value in your resource bundles. And many more things.

You can make sure that `equals()` is equivalent to `==` with enums.

All of this **defines** an `enum`.

If you want something "similar" to an enum, then write it: it's not too hard.

Answer (score 2):

It would break comparisons. You want

```
if (myEnumValue == yourEnumValue)
{
}
```

to work, if there could be multiple instances of the same enum value, there's no guarantee that reference-based testing like this would work. Compare with strings.

Comment: why can't i give a different value through the constructor,rather than giving the same value

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess it would cause confusion, because people expect to be able to compare against enums using `==`.  Being able to clone would break the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

If you had two enums then the following instruction could be true or false...

```
public boolean isEnumBlack(EnumType enum) {
    if (enum == EnumType.BLACK) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then if you called this method with an "instance" of the EnumType, BLACK... then it would not return true.

`isEnumBlack(BLACK)` would return false, even though according to the code it should be returning true. Enum's would no longer be enum's!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the other good answers, it would break `EnumSet`. `EnumSet` is implemented, depending on the size of the enum, as a single `long` or an array of `long`s, where each bit represents the inclusion or exclusion of one particular enum value. If the number and order of enums were not constant, this would not work.